# Unsubscribe user with one subscriber key but many email addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, subscriber-key, unsubscribe

I have one user with one subscriber key but with different email addresses in a data extension. If I send through Journey builder, I can target all the email addresses by setting the field in "Use email attribute from Entry Source" (this way i'm not targeting the only email available for this subscriber key in All Subscribers).

My question is: how can I manage the unsubscribes in this case? If only one email address unsubscribe and the rest don't (for the same user), will the subscriber key appeared unsubscribed in All Subscribers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one email address can be bound with a subscriber key.

When you send an email with setting the field "Use email attribute from Entry Source" in journey builder, this will update the All Subscribers List email address.

Therefore, the email address for the same subscriber key will be overwritten every time a record in the DE source is used for the send.

---

If the subscriber goes to any email send and optout in Profile Center, that person will be opted out in All Subscribers List. (this also has the same behavior when using Unsub Center)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it’s very clear

Comment: @malena if you find it helpful, kindly mark it as an accepted answer, thanks.